# how to resize a div as soon as the document is loaded

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to do this in javascript:

```
  var w = 1280;
  var h = 1024;
  window.onload = function()
  {
    if (w > 0)
      document.getElementById('flashdiv').style.width=w;
    else
      document.getElementById('flashdiv').style.width="100%";


   alert(document.getElementById('flashdiv').style.width);

    if (h > 0)
      document.getElementById('flashdiv').style.height=h;
    else
      document.getElementById('flashdiv').style.height="100%";
  };
```

but it doesnt seem to resize the div at all. what am i missing here?

Comment: Just curious, why not to use jQuery for this?

Comment: i have tried jquery too like this $('#flashdiv').resizeTo(w, h); but it also doesnt seem to work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

style.width is a string so you have to do

```
document.getElementById('flashdiv').style.width=w+"px";
```